# nodejs request body as json

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following curl:

```sh
curl 'http://localhost:9008/updated' \ 
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, /' \ 
  -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36' \ 
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \ 
  -H 'Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.9' \ 
  -data-raw '{"data":[{"id":"12345"}]}'
```

In NodeJS, I receive the `req.body` as an object:

```json
{ '{"data":[{"id":"12345"}]}' }
```

but I should receive as a JSON like in the curl:

```json
{"data":[{"id":"12345"}]}
```

This is my handler:

```js
router.post('/updated', express.json(), function (req, res) {
   logger.info(req.body) // output as object, and It should be a JSON
});
```

Any ideas to remove the extra `{` or receive a JSON like in the curl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` to `Content-Type: application/json` in your curl command

Comment: Is there a way to edit the nodejs code without changing the curl petition?
I mean, the curl petition will affect other services so for now I am avoiding to change the curl options :(

Comment: Gavin, maybe explain why you would do that. It, probably, will also address OPs comment.

Comment: I think Gavin is right because application/x-www-form-urlencoded is for data like  key=value&key=value and my curl data is a json so it should be application/json.
Am I right?

Comment: @Minniek, its true what you say. `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is for key values pairs like you would have it in an URL query. The body you post doesn't comply to that, in the long run you should change it. However, this doesn't exactly explain to me why express is parsing the body the way you show. This would require looking into the `express.json` code to see if it does something based on the content type or not.

Comment: Ideally the curl should send `Content-Type: application/json` if you have a  complex data format. Also read http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html to learn more about body parsing

Comment: Try to curl with -data instead of -data-raw

Comment: @ask4you, good call. I have also thought about that already. I had in the past problems with data and raw data.

Comment: @GavinHaynes, I am not sure if body-parser is used when using express.json. AFAIK body-parser is deprecated.